# code that parse email from name string c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to code  parse button that 
When I typed skw2030@gmail.com email address
messagbox pops up up with 
User Name: skw2030
Domain Name: gmail.com

thus, i used code to remove "@" but when I click the parse button,
it always removes first letter of user name, ex) kw2030...
what should I do??

```
private void btnParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = Convert.ToString(txtEmail.Text);
        email = email.Trim();
        if (email.Contains("@"))
            email = email.Remove(0, 1);
        int IndexDomain = email.IndexOf("@") + 1;

        string UserName = email.Substring(0 , IndexDomain - 1);
        string DomainName = email.Substring(IndexDomain);

        MessageBox.Show("User name:"  +  UserName.ToString() + "\n"
          + "Domain Name:" + DomainName.ToString(), "Parsed String");                   

    }
```

Comment: You are explicitly removing the first character of the string in your `if` block for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

Few suggestions:

- The input from the `txtEmail` is already a string you need not to
  convert it again as string.
- if the given mail id not `"@"` then its better to show an alert, that the entered mail id is not valid.
- It is not needed to remove the particular character; split the string into `2` based on the character. that gives you the required result.
- The [`String.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.string.remove(v=vs.110).aspx)will accept two parameters, first one denotes the start index and the second one will be the number of characters: So if you want to perform this remove operation you need to do like this(but this is not necessary here):

  ```
  int IndexDomain = email.IndexOf("@");
  email = email.Remove(IndexDomain, 1);
  ```
- Another better option is formatting your output message using placeholders;

Now consider the snippet:

```
string email = txtEmail.Text.Trim();; // "skw2030@gmail.com"      
if (email.Contains("@"))
{
   string[] addressElements = email.Split('@');
   MessageBox.Show(String.Format("User name: {0} \n Domain Name: {1}",addressElements[0],addressElements[1]), "Parsed String");
}
else
MessageBox.Show("invalid Mail");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use split method of string. Like that:

```
string email = "abc@example.com";
string[] arr = email.Split('@');
```

It would give you 2 elements array with first being name (abc) ,  second being domain (example.com).

By the way,  in your case here is the problem:

```
email = email.Remove(0, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this was the problem ...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just want to split the string into two, right?

In an email, everything on the left of @ is the username, and on the right is the domain. To split the email into two parts, use the `Split()` method:

```
string email = "abc@def.com";
string[] twoParts = email.Split('@');
```

Now the array `twoParts` contain two elements - "abc" and "def.com" and that's exactly what you wanted, right?

```
string username = twoParts[0];
string domainName = twoParts[1];
```

But wait! What if the email is invalid? To check whether the email is invalid, you can just check the length of the array:

```
if (twoParts.Length != 2) {
    // show error message
}
```

Of course you should check that before you get the username and domain.

Comment: Thanks alot! i could not imagine using array. this could be so simple..

Comment: @KyungwonSuh if you think my answer answers you question please consider accepting it by clicking on that tick.

Answer (score 0):

This line below is removing 1 character from index 0 of your email string.

```
email = email.Remove(0, 1);
```

The `If (email.Contains("@"))` can be used to ensure user has entered an valid email to handle exceptions being thrown. You should modify your code like so:

```
private void btnParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string email = Convert.ToString(txtEmail.Text);
    email = email.Trim();
    if (email.Contains("@"))
    {
        //email = email.Remove(0, 1); <--- Remove this
        int IndexDomain = email.IndexOf("@") + 1;

        string UserName = email.Substring(0 , IndexDomain - 1);
        string DomainName = email.Substring(IndexDomain);

        MessageBox.Show("User name:"  +  UserName.ToString() + "\n"
          + "Domain Name:" + DomainName.ToString(), "Parsed String");
    }
    else
    {
        //Tell users that the email is invalid.
        //For example: MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email");
    }
}
```

---

Anyway, like others have mentioned, you should definitely consider `String.Split`. Basically it separates a string at user-defined character. So if you do:

```
string emailArray = email.Split('@');
```

Your `UserName` and `DomainName` are now simply:

```
string UserName = emailArray[0];
string DomainName = emailArray[1];
```

Much simpler right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Substring** method for string. Like that:

```
private void btnParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string email = txtEmail.Text.Trim(); // your email address      
     if (email.Contains("@"))
     {
         var userName = email.Substring(0, email.IndexOf('@'));
         var domainName = email.Substring(email.IndexOf('@') + 1, email.Length - email.IndexOf('@') - 1);
         MessageBox.Show("User name:"  +  userName + "\n" + "Domain Name:" + domainName, "Parsed String"); 
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Invalid email");
     }
}
```